# Can I create a field that updates with data from another object?

Tags: custom-object, lookup

If I have a Shipping object that includes many fields, but the two for this purpose are Mailing_State and Rush (which is a checkbox) and I'd like to create another field called Time which holds the amount of time it takes to ship. I was thinking that I would create an object with the fields ID_State, Rush_Time, and Regular_Time. Then on the Shipping object, Time would be a formula *like*

```
If (Rush=True, If (Mailing_State = ID_State, Rush_Time), If (Mailing_State = ID_State, Regular_Time))
```

I'm rather certain I may have to do this with an Apex Trigger, but if it can be accomplished with a workflow, that would be greatly appreciated. I understand that it can be as a formula with a Case statement, but that would be very long and could be difficult to update if the shipping time increases/decreases from where it is today.
If it must be Apex, any resource better than the Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use an Apex Code trigger for this. It's easy, and here's how:

1. Create a "Custom Setting", type List, with two number fields for normal and rush delivery time in days.
2. Populate this list setting with the delivery timings.
3. Use the following trigger (adjust for naming differences):

---

```
trigger updateShippingTime on Shipping__c (before insert, before update) {
    for(Shipping__c record: Trigger.new) {
        if(Delivery_Time__c.get(record.Mailing_State__c) != null) {
            record.Delivery_Time__c = record.Rush__c?  
                Delivery_Time__c.get(record.Mailing_State__c).Rush_Time__c:
                Delivery_Time__c.get(record.Mailing_State__c).Normal_Time__c;
        }
    }
}
```

---

NOTE: You will probably want to create a Visualforce page for modifying the settings, because any change to the custom setting will involve a mass recalculation of delivery times. Batch Apex would be useful here.

---

```
public class recalculateDistances implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    Set<String> states;

    public recalculateDistances(Set<String> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Mailing_State__c, Rush__c FROM Shipping__c WHERE Mailing_State__c IN :states]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.batchableContext bc, Shipping__c[] records) {
        database.update(records, false);
    }
    public void finish(Database.batchableContext bc) {
    // nothing to do
    }
}
```

All that's left here is a test method for testing your batch class and trigger:

```
@isTest
class TestShippingClasses {
    static void test() {
        Delivery_Time__c t = new Delivery_Time(Name='SC', Rush_Time__c=3, Normal_Time__c=5);
        insert t;
        Shipping__c record = new Shipping__c(Name='Some Place', Rush__c=true, Mailing_State__c='SC');
        insert record;
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new recalculateDistances(new Set<String> { 'SC' }));
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```